# How to plan a query that has no where clause to prevent non-indexed reads

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

There is a thing that bugs me. When I execute a query without any `where`-clause or `order by`-clause like

```
select ID
  from M_TABLE;
```

the reads are non-indexed.

I need this query to be that simple because it is used inside of a `select`-statement for a view.
Non-indexed reads have a nasty smell of bad performance to me. So I avoid them where possible.

In case of this extremely simple query, I would just like to use the primary key to make the reads indexed. But when I try to add a plan statement like this

```
select ID
  from M_TABLE t
  plan (t index (PK_M_TABLE));
```

the error messages

> index  cannot be used in the specified plan.
>
> index PK_M_TABLE cannot be used in the specified plan.

are returned.

**How can I force the reads to be indexed?** Have I misspelled something in the plan statement? I had a look at [the documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-select-plan) but can't see a syntax error and I think it is actually not a syntax error.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE M_TABLE (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE M_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_M_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

**Note:**
I've posted a possible workaround underneath. Feel free to vote it up, if you think it is the only possible solution. But if there are other solutions than this, post them as additional answers, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a where clause (or order by) that uses an index, then plan natural is very likely the best plan to use, especially if you are planning to read the entire table.

Firebird does not have clustered indexes, so even for indexed reads it will eventually have to read from the table data pages themselves. The index read itself might be faster, but reading the data randomly from the data pages will likely be more expensive than reading the data in data page order. The only exception I know of is if you have a lot of updates and deletes that produce a lot of garbage and backversions.

Your concerns about this being a view is - as far as I know - unfounded. When using views in another query, Firebird will inline the view and optimize for the query as a whole. Applying an order by in your view as in your answer might actually **hurt** performance when the view is used in a non-trivial query.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to force the reads to be indexed is to add a `order by`-clause on the indexed field in question:

```
select ID
  from M_TABLE
  order by ID;
```

Thus, the plan statement `plan (M_TABLE order PK_M_TABLE)` is used internally.